# Simplest solution to make Android application run with system user android:sharedUserId=“android.uid.system” on android studio on windows

Tags: android

I can see people suggesting generating a signed release using `platform.pk8 platform.x509.pem` but on Windows I cannot find these two files. For the solution currently, I am thinking of having a Linux system and setting up an Android studio there to generate the build of my app. Then I will be able to find a `platform.pk8 platform.x509.pem` from this directory `build/target/product/security` and use them to generate a keystore file which will be used to sign the app.

Other confusion says I should clone the AOSP in the system and generate a build as a system service.
The question is what will be the simplest thing for me to make my Android application run with system `userId`?

I have tried signing the app but getting this:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/de.blinkt.openvpn-1: Package de.blinkt.openvpn has no signatures that match those in shared user android.uid.system; ignoring!]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: On what device do you want to install your system app? Because the keys included in AOSP are not the one Google or other manufacturer use hir signing their Android OS. So these keys won't help you.

Comment: It will run on an AllWinner device running which is running AOSP version of Android not the one with Google play.